Title of an action movie from late 80s, early 90s where Soviet is invading USA
The little I remember is that the USSR is invading the USA and we are following a group of students/children. They might have hid in the mountains, and I think there was a scene in a school. The group of students called themselves wolverines I think.
I loved the movie when I saw it many years ago, but I was too young to remember the title. It is most likely from the late 80s or early 90s. What is the title of this movie?

Just 2 words in google brings this answer up 1st choice: movie, wolverines.

I remembered the wolverines part as I was forming the question.

Google 3 words: movie, soviet, invasion. Same result, 1st choice.

This sounds exactly like Red Dawn (the original from 1984 with the good old Soviets, not the 2012 remake with North Koreans):

From out of the sky, Soviet, Nicaraguan, and Cuban troops begin
  landing on the football field of a Colorado high school. In seconds,
  the paratroopers have attacked the school and sent a group of
  teenagers fleeing into the mountains. Armed only with hunting rifles,
  pistols, and bows and arrows, the teens struggle to survive the bitter
  winter and the Soviet KGB patrols hunting for them. Eventually,
  trouble arises when they kill a group of Soviet soldiers on patrol in
  the highlands. Soon they will wage their own guerrilla warfare against
  the invading Soviet troops-under the banner of 'Wolverines!'


Note the remake was originally China (see on location photos at http://www.reddawnmovienews.com/index.php/red-dawn-on-location-photos ), but pressure from PRC investors/distributors required changing to NK. This required some pretty massive digital changes, as the movie was "in the can" already, done, finished. Do also note for the remake, we are advised in-film that Russia has the East Coast, and that NK has the Pacific Northwest; it is implied that the PRC is also involved, possibly Mexico (though it may just have been in the way of someone else).

"Interestingly" this movie lent its name to the Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2 level based around a Russian invasion of America.

@DaveM Well, it lent its whole concept to Homefront afterall.

Aye, that's true.  Red Alert, too.  The only reason I mentioned it was that the level on MW2 was called "Wolverines".  I've only just now worked out why. :)

@Smithers - When the original came out, the Soviets weren't all that happy about being the bad guys either. However, back then there was almost no international market, so Hollywood didn't care what other countries thought.

I believe it was Red Dawn the original movie.
Underlying theme in this film - there were 2 Cold Wars. America aka US
Yes 2 themes. not one. The theme that jumps out is the USA and Soviet Union defense and offense relationships-the "expected" we are enemies who don't trust one another and each country feels it is superior to the other and , with the second one between the U.S. and the USSR aka Soviet Union.
America does not feel teenagers are responsible during the Cold War.
The USA teens do not go down and enlist in the Armed Services because it is expected from thier peers and elders and government.
Russia believes teens are responsible and productive. Yeah but their 
political system doesn't aLLow laziness in teenagers. 
Do the Russsian solders have respect for the American teens - yes 

This does not appear to add anything beyond some personal opinion to Napoleon Wilson's accepted answer from two years ago.
